# MyFaces ExtScripting

Tags: groovy, jsf-2.2, myfaces

I'm a satisfied (and historical ...) myfaces user and I'm looking for a JSF 2.2 rapid prototyping environment.
I've already used Groovy in other projects so the natural choice should be Apache MyFaces Extension Scripting.
These are problems:

1) [Home page](http://myfaces.apache.org/ext-scripting) don't works (... is the project yet maintained ? ...)

2) Trying to follow [example config](http://myfaces.apache.org/extensions/scripting/exampleconfig.html) I've noticed that the web.xml settings are **wrong** so:

```
<param-name>org.apache.myfaces.FACES_INIT_PLUGINS</param-name>
<param-value>org.apache.myfaces.extensions.scripting.servlet.StartupServletContextPluginChainLoader</param-value>
```

must be updated to:

```
...
<param-value>org.apache.myfaces.extensions.scripting.jsf.startup.StartupServletContextPluginChainLoader</param-value>
...
```

3) The [example war](https://repository.apache.org/content/repositories/releases/org/apache/myfaces/extensions/scripting/myfaces20-extscript-helloworld/1.0.5/myfaces20-extscript-helloworld-1.0.5.war) (deployed in a clean tomcat 7.0 instance) **don't works** (no errors, no results ...)

Have anyone suggestions for me ? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: PLEASE do a **little** more searching or intelligent navigation. On the http://myfaces.apache.org is a different extscripting page link: http://myfaces.apache.org/extensions/scripting/index.html. Took me 10 seconds to find

Comment: I've navigated to that link clicking on the ES Home icon (starting from http://myfaces.apache.org/extensions/scripting/index.html) ....

Comment: Most likely an old reference then that they forgot to update... The link in your and my comment seems to point to a 'homepage'

Comment: Sure. First and second issues only require site updates ;-). The real problem is third issue ....